# SoftLayer Account Lockdown Request

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can we use "disableLockedAccount" method of "SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request service" as a user?

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request/disableLockedAccount

Did anyone try to execute it?

At this moment, I don't have any idea about "SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_RequestInitParameters".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute this command the brand should have a special attribute enabled (You should contact Sales for it), and this command can be only executed by **master user from brand master account**.

Regarding to: I don't have any idea about "SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_RequestInitParameters"

You should send the ID that is returned from the [SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request::disconnectCompute](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request/disconnectCompute) command

Comment: I got the following error after executing "SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request::disconnectCompute".

SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Permission denied.

Comment: I got the following reply from SoftLayer Sales support.
"Customers cannot disconnect or disable the account. Customers need to cancel all the servers and services on their account. As long as there are no active billing items on the account, it will be automatically disabled after a short period.
"

Comment: That's the main requirement to create de lockdown request, you should have no any active billing item in your account (servers, services, etc)