# how to use AccountLockdown's disableLockedAccount function via API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we are testing AccountLockdownTest API

below a value is result.

- disconnectCompute - Complete
- reconnectCompute - Complete
- cancelRequest - Complete
- getAccountHistory - Complete
- disableLockedAccount - Queue

the last function (disableLockedAccount) is continuously queuing

I tried a several times but the result is same and the configured date is over.

I have two question.

1. first question

> why don't the last function complete?

2. second question

> how to use disableLockedAccount function about an account without any resources?
>
> ( disableLockedAccount needs a request ID of disconnectCompute)

Answer (score 0):

1) This could be due that there is still active billable items under the account (or in the process of cancellation), after this it will be automatically disabled after a short period.

2) It means you need to send the result id from disconnectCompute method as you mentioned it completed, that method should return an integer, you need to send that value to the method.

For more information about this review the following:

[SoftLayer Account Lockdown request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186928/softlayer-account-lockdown-request)

[What's the best way to clean up SoftLayer accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074104/whats-the-best-way-to-clean-up-softlayer-accounts)

Comment: I already sent the result id of disconnectCompute but the result is same.